# Using regex how to capture words/numbers 2 spaces after a defined pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a body of text:

```
text = 'DEFINING PATHWAY /n \s 126 HI. DEPT. INIT\n E. OFFICER\'S SIGNATURE\n N/A\n EQUIPMENT 1x23\n N/A\ A.  B.  C.  D.  E.  F.  G.  FAULT REPAIR12 _ 23 E. OFFICER\'S SIGNATURE\n 00039501\n EQUIPMENT_SERVER_COMPUTER 12 85\n 1362\n \n 7\n 1\n 2\n CV031\n \n 4. METER\nSECTION IV SUMMARY\n 46. SPEC PURPOSE  A.  B.  C.  D.  E.  F.  G.  H.\n38. MAINT. MAN\n 39. RATE\n 40. SUPERVISOR\n 41. PRI\n 42. T/A\nC. DIV. INIT\n D. DEPT. INIT\n E. OFFICER\'S SIGNATURE\n X4549803078\n EQUIPMENT3_4d HTA CHIP\n X&6a\n'
```

I would like to find the words and numbers 2 spaces after `OFFICER\'S SIGNATURE\n` every time and pull the text and numbers until the next delimiter `\n`

for example: `OFFICER\'S SIGNATURE\n N/A\n EQUIPMENT 1x23\n`

Skip `N/A\n` and find `EQUIPMENT 1x23`

intended matches from this body of text

```
matches = ['EQUIPMENT 1x23', 'EQUIPMENT_SERVER_COMPUTER 12 85', 'EQUIPMENT3_4d HTA CHIP']
```

Below is a list of unsuccessful patterns I have tried that have returned an empty list

```
equipment_pattern =  r"OFFICER\'S SIGNATURE\n(?:. *?\n)*(.+?)\n"
equipment_pattern =  r"OFFICER\'S SIGNATURE\n[^\n]*\n(.+?)\n"
equipment_pattern =  r"OFFICER\'S SIGNATURE\n(?:[^\n]*\n)*(.+?)\n"
equipment_pattern = r"SIGNATURE\n[^\\n]*\\n((?:[^\\n]*\\n)*.+?)\\n"
equipment_pattern = r"OFFICER\'S SIGNATURE\\n([^\\n]+)"
equipment_pattern = r"OFFICER\'S SIGNATURE\n([^\n]*?)\n"
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `'` in regular expressions.

Comment: You also don't need to escape it in a string delimited by `"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> equipment_pattern =  r"OFFICER'S SIGNATURE\n[^\n]*\n(.+)"
>>> re.findall(equipment_pattern, text)
[' EQUIPMENT 1x23', ' EQUIPMENT_SERVER_COMPUTER 12 85', ' EQUIPMENT3_4d HTA CHIP']
```

This matches `OFFICER'S SIGNATURE` followed by another line that it skips, then captures the next line after that.

You don't need `\n` at the end. Make the last `.*` greedy by removing the `?`, and it will match until the next newline.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Python's excellent [PyPI regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) (roughy similar to the PCRE regex engine except that it also supports variable-length lookbehinds), you could attempt to match the string with the following regular expression (which does not use a capture group):

```
regex.findall(r'\bOFFICER'S SIGNATURE\n [^ ]* \K.*', str)
  #=> [['EQUIPMENT 1x23', 'EQUIPMENT_SERVER_COMPUTER 12 85',
  #     'EQUIPMENT3_4d HTA CHIP']
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/71sCVZ/1) ¯\*(ツ)*/¯ [Python demo](https://tio.run/##jVJNT8MwDL33V7wTGwiFtunGduAQ2myNoG1I08FEYQLxNQnK1O0wfv1wAKFdmJDy5MR@eXYcLz5WL@8N32zmb4v3doX28flx7XnLVYsTdBI5UrnKx9DCppdiiqMG9RJB2EeqGBKpLQMxbN1AMhSjkYqlqTslSjXOha2MpEh@JFz8olI6k7lFsA75jxuCAaeEmJAQSAUjwthZUZ1bGKmFMkGIGUK@I4vv@3zY84PtVLNSmok0s7jIdGWlocox6BEj4P2QDK1jdyK4YzzxefDtjhgySTfqppSxVUUONUFZZZkwUxfuM5RaxtCV0UUpsfMhKasbPiBFoXLrTE4SfMhghHWlRz6pVZpqVWVhnCNg0Ea5XchgXf9IN1GT324n/@7@VdSLhgOf@8eD7dbwWfSA1ArEqdKOtte/q5uO57XPa/r6tlPf/yF4fYubA9Rn7IDYi3berLpfU8Oe5s3D3etrlxQOQRO0v@9tNp8)

The directive `\K` (which is not supported by Python's conventional regex engine) causes the start of the match to be reset to the current location of the engine's string pointer and to discard any previously-consumed characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r'EQUIPMENT[A-Z0-9_]*.*?(?=\n)', text)

['EQUIPMENT 1x23', 'EQUIPMENT_SERVER_COMPUTER 12 85', 'EQUIPMENT3_4d HTA CHIP']
```

Comment: What if the string does not contain `"OFFICER'S SIGNATURE\n"`?